# Suricata integration with TheHive

Tags: integration, alert, suricata, threat-model

i'm trying to do an integration between Suricata and TheHive so that Suricata sends alerts to TheHive. Does anyone know how to do?

Consider that thehive is running on a machine in a docker-compose and Suricata is on another machine.

I'm studying the environments to understand how to do it but I can't. I had thought about using pfsense but I don't know if I can. I don't want to have to write a python script using thehive4py.